# Update query for Mysql Not working using JPA

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa

Here is a query that works fine in Mysql

```
    set @on = 2;
UPDATE `knowledgeapps`.`article`
SET

`OrderNo` = (@on:=@on + 1)
WHERE OrderNo >1;
```

Can someone help me translate it to JPA? I have tried to translate it using HQL and using native queries. Exceptions for both the cases. I think a fresh viewpoint might help.
Thanks

Comment: why the negative vote? any data i need to add? isnt the q clear?

Comment: "I have tried to translate it using HQL" ... right, and what was your attempt and what happened? That is how things work on this site. It isn't a code writing service

Answer (score 0):

Added a stored procedure for it and called it. Working fine now. Earlier it was not allowing the code @on + 1.